# How to use a drop-shadow effects in IE on a div with after and befor pseudo elements?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have a wizard with divs with two arrows with this html

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: flex;
}

div.arrow {
  width: 261.5px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.current {
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 3px 7px grey);
}

div.arrow::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border: 0 solid #d3d3d3;
  border-width: 25px 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 100%;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #d3d3d3;
}

div.arrow::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border: 0 solid #d3d3d3;
  border-width: 25px 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: -20px;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow">Previous status</div>
  <div class="arrow current">Current status</div>
</div>
```

I have a class called "current" where I applied a drop-shadow effect. It works fine but IE doesn't support it and I can't find a solution for solving this issue. Any help to solve this problem? I can't edit the existing css...

Here a codepen: https://codepen.io/andy_888/pen/bGdKxjv

Thank you

Comment: Which version of IE is it ?

Comment: It's Internet Explorer 11

Comment: okay, you better let it go and eventually darken the bg for that browser. setting a workaround will not be worth the time spent . You can filter browsers via `@support` to give it them the dropshadow filter see   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports  set a different bg-color to `.current` and pseudos, then reset it to normal and set the drop shadow inside the `@support` block

Comment: It's not clear...the result has to be the same

Comment: take the time to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports and learn how to use it, then it will become clear: for browsers supporting dropshadow , dropshadow will be used and you can reset background to actual background. for others , set any background color instead shadow . so you have a different  visual but not the shadow . .

Comment: Yes, it's ok. But I can't do it...the behaviour must be the same...

Comment: okay , you gonna waste lots of time for very little, anyhow, here is the idea of how to deal with this : https://jsbin.com/qirebohuju/1/edit?html,css,output IE11 and Win7 are not supported anymore , what about IE8 or 9 or 10 ? IE7 really was the worse .. forget it ;)

Comment: And I want to add a border to the shape instead to add background color?